# Information On How Fake USB Drives Work

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive

So I wanted to create a fake 2TB USB flash drive (for comedic purposes only), and came across [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/270194/how-is-the-capacity-of-a-harddisk-faked). Apparently someone bought a fake hard drive from China, and inside was a few nuts to give it some weight, and a (probably very low capacity) USB flash drive that had some sort of "looped mode".

Essentially what would happen was whenever you would write a large file (larger then the real capacity of the actual flash drive inside) it would "re-write" itself, AKA erasing itself and starting over, and continuing to do that until the file transfer was complete.

I was already able to make my USB flash drive appear as 2TB (made a Linux SH script, will provide if requested), but I'd really like to know how they are set to "re-write" themselves.

Thanks in advance!
Leo

This question is different from the one [here](https://superuser.com/questions/270194/how-is-the-capacity-of-a-harddisk-faked) because I was requesting more detailed information on how these faked USB devices were set into "loop" mode. The other question was general information about fake USB devices.

Comment: I'm curious to see the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I have seen, sellers modify the firmware of the controller on the drive.

Sellers are known to do one of the four:

- Set a "loop back" mode, overwriting data when needed.
- When over the actual capacity, write the data to a "dev/null" like area
- When over capacity, ignore any further data (usually displays an error)
- Change the file allocation table (FAT) on certain file systems.

I haven't been able to find anything on how this is done exactly, probably as it's a "trade secret". It's fairly easy to detect, because after the physical space has run out (the 1GB, 2GB, or 8GB chip), the files will be corrupted.

Web Links:

http://www.rmprepusb.com/tutorials/-fake-usb-flash-memory-drives

http://www.passmark.com/support/bit_fake_USB_detection.htm

Comment: Ah, okay. So it's probably not possible to set this "loop" mode without modifying the firmware of the USB controller. The errors that appear when the real capacity is overrun will happen of you modify the FAT partition table to fake the size of the partition. Thanks for the info!