# Directory copied into USB drive disappeared: input/output error

Tags: linux, hard-drive, bash, usb

I have copied a folder with a bunch of files onto a 2 TB USB drive, which I formatted as NTFS. Some time later, I inserted the USB drive into the computer to look at the files. When I opened the directory, the files weren't there. The directory was still there, but all the files have disappeared. I tried to navigate to that directory within the USB drive. I was able to `cd` into that directory, but `ls` returned an input/output error. Attempting to create a new file using the `touch` command also produced the same error. What is going on?

```
/media/user/0EB2CB2FB2CB1A5B/monthly_reports$ ls
ls: reading directory '.': Input/output error
/media/user/0EB2CB2FB2CB1A5B/monthly_reports$ touch file.txt
touch: cannot touch 'file.txt': Input/output error
```

---

I inserted the USB drive into my Windows PC as an experiment. When I attempt to open that directory using the File Explorer, a message box pops up:

```
Location not available
F:\monthy_reports is not accessible.
The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.
```

Comment: Most likely you forgot to safely remove the drive before unplugging it.

Comment: @gronostaj No, that's not it, this happened when the drive was already plugged in.

Comment: Where did you get this drive? What type of USB drive is it? Is it a new drive or an old one?

Comment: @Mokubai I got this drive on Amazon. It is a 2TB USB drive. It is a new drive.

Comment: Was the drive suspiciously cheap? What type of drive is it? A 2TB USB "stick" would surprise me and could be fake, but an HDD would be normal. For example I would expect [this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/External-Ultra-Slim-Portable-Compatible-Notebook/dp/B0B461S6N1) to be a fake drive and probably a 16GB stick in disguise, while I would trust [this one](https://www.amazon.co.uk/WD-Elements-Portable-External-Drive/dp/B06W55K9N6)

Comment: @Mokubai Yes, the USB drive was a cheap one, with a price comparable to the first one. However when plugged in the USB drive and examined it's properties in the file explorer, it was listed as the full 2TB.

Comment: Many of those drives have a fake capacity that appears at first glance to be correct but then appears to overwrite or "lose" data as you write to them. Some info is at [How is the capacity of a harddisk faked?](https://superuser.com/questions/270194/how-is-the-capacity-of-a-harddisk-faked) as well as https://superuser.com/questions/1169039/information-on-how-fake-usb-drives-work

Comment: Try running [h2testw](https://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Miscellaneous/H2testw.shtml) on it to find out if the drive is "good" or fake. Some other alternatives at https://www.geckoandfly.com/22803/detect-fake-usb-flash-drives-sd-cards-ssd-disk/

Comment: @Galaxy It's a fake. Please report it.